# How to remove all lines from a text file starting at first empty line?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

What is the best way to remove all lines from a text file starting at first empty line in Bash? External tools (awk, sed...) can be used!

Example

```
1: ABC
2: DEF
3:
4: GHI
```

Line 3 and 4 should be removed and the remaining content should be saved in a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `AWK`:

```
$ awk '/^$/{exit} 1' test.txt > output.txt
```

Contents of **output.txt**

```
$ cat output.txt 
ABC
DEF
```

Walkthrough: For lines that matches ^$ (start-of-line, end-of-line), exit (the whole script). For all lines, print the whole line -- of course, we won't get to this part after a line has made us exit.

Answer (score 8):

With [`GNU sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
sed '/^$/Q' "input_file.txt" > "output_file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bet there are some more clever ways to do this, but here's one using bash's 'read' builtin.  The question asks us to keep lines before the blank in one file and send lines after the blank to another file.   You could send some of standard out one place and some another if you are willing to use 'exec' and reroute stdout mid-script, but I'm going to take a simpler approach and use a command line argument to let me know where the post-blank data should go:

```
#!/bin/bash

# script takes as argument the name of the file to send data once a blank line
# found
found_blank=0
while read stuff; do
    if [ -z $stuff ] ; then
            found_blank=1
    fi
    if [ $found_blank ] ; then
            echo $stuff > $1
    else
            echo $stuff
    fi
done
```

run it like this:

```
$ ./delete_from_empty.sh rest_of_stuff < demo
```

output is:

```
ABC
DEF
```

and 'rest_of_stuff' has

```
GHI
```

if you want the before-blank lines to go somewhere else besides stdout, simply redirect:

```
$ ./delete_from_empty.sh after_blank < input_file > before_blank
```

and  you'll end up with two new files: after_blank and before_blank.

Comment: Some comments: in the current state, you will ignore backslash characters. Use `read -r` to prevent this (see `man read`). Second, you can get rid of the `$found_blank` test, by just doing your first check directly: `if [ -z "$stuff" ]; then echo "$stuff" > "$1"; else echo "$stuff"; fi`. Also it is important to quote your `$stuff` otherwise lines with only spaces might be ignored. And you can get rid of `stuff` and use `REPLY` instead which is the bash builtin that represents the answer of `read`

Answer (score 1):

Perl version

```
 perl -e '
        open $fh, ">","stuff";  
        open $efh, ">", "rest_of_stuff"; 
        while(<>){
           if ($_ !~ /\w+/){
                 $fh=$efh;
           } 
           print $fh $_;
         }
            ' demo
```

This creates two output files and iterates over the demo data. When it hits a blank line, it flips the output from one file to the other.

Creates

stuff:

```
ABC
DEF
```

rest_of_stuff:

```
<blank line>
GHI
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk would be:

```
awk -vRS= '1;{exit}' file
```

By setting the record separator `RS` to be an empty string, we define the records as *paragraphs* separated by a sequence of empty lines. It is now easily to adapt this to select the nth block as:

```
awk -vRS= '(FNR==n){print;exit}' file
```

There is a problem with this method when processing files with a DOS line-ending (CRLF). There will be no empty lines as there will always be a CR in the line. But this problem applies to all presented methods.