# Remove everything starting from the first blank line in a text file

Tags: regex, linux, unix, text, command-line

I have a text file from which I want to remove all the lines beginning with the first blank line, preferably using some standard Unix tool like sed/awk.

Comment: You want to remove in a file, each line beginning with a space ?

Comment: Never mind -- I found a duplicate in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254011/best-way-to-remove-all-lines-from-a-text-file-starting-at-first-empty-line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '/^$/ {exit}{print}' < data
```

Sample input:

> ```
> one two thre
> four five six
> seven
>
> eight nine ten
> eleven twelve
> thirteen
>
> fourteen fifteen
> THE END
> ```

Sample output:

> ```
> # awk '/^$/ {exit}{print}' < data
> one two thre
> four five six
> seven
> ```

BTW, If your "blank lines" could include spaces and/or tabs, use:

```
'/^[ \t]*$/ {exit}{print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

With Perl

```
perl -pe '/^\s+$/ and exit' < in.txt > out.txt
```

the `-p` adds `while(<>) {` and `print }` around the script specified on the commandline with `-e`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed -i '/^\s*$/,$d' file
```