# sed: remove matching line and everything after

Tags: sed

I'm trying to remove all lines after the first blank line in a file with a git filter using sed.

This seems to remove everything **after** the blank line

```
sed -i '/^$/q' test.rpt
```

How do I also include the blank line itself to be deleted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to remove all lines from a text file starting at first empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254011/best-way-to-remove-all-lines-from-a-text-file-starting-at-first-empty-line)

Comment: @RaviSaroch it's asking for the best way, not the sed way

Comment: @oguzismail sir, sed is also included in it.

Answer (score 4):

If this is GNU sed, just use `Q` instead of `q`.

```
sed -i '/^$/Q' test.rpt
```

For BSD sed, use `-n` switch to suppress automatic printing, and print lines manually. E.g:

```
sed -n -i '/^$/q;p' test.rpt
```

---

PS: You might want to change the regex to `^[[:blank:]]*$` to regard lines of all blank characters as blank lines as well.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to make it work in git as well. When I run this command from the MINGW64 console it works fine, but in git it gives an error about input file, so I removed the -i command. But then it just doesn't do anything :/

Comment: @Anova Does it at least print the lines until the blank?

Comment: Yes, works perfectly in print in the console up to the line before the blank

Comment: So, in git, why don't you save its output to an intermediate file and replace the original file with it then? Isn't it possible?

Comment: Like `sed ... actualfile > tempfile && mv tempfile actualfile`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
sed -i '/^$/,$ d' inputfile
```