# Removing all lines after blank line with sed and awk

Tags: awk, sed

I want to remove everything after a blank line INCLUDING the blank line. Is there a sed or awk command to do this?

I have a file that looks like:

```
text
text
moretext
evenmore text


sometexthere
text
```

I want to remove everything after the first blank line. I want my output to be:

```
text
text
moretext
evenmore text
```

I'm not sure how to do this though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: See also [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove all lines from a text file starting at first empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254011/remove-all-lines-from-a-text-file-starting-at-first-empty-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '/^$/{exit}1' ./input/file
```

Comment: save a char `awk '!NF{exit}1' file` ;)

Comment: @jaypalsingh that's not exactly the same, yours will match lines with spaces and tabs as well, whereas `/^$/` will match only completely empty lines